# Java Sax mysterious

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

I have this xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new2.xsl"?>
<patients>
    <patient>
        <stoixeia_astheni>
            <arithmos_eksetasis>1</arithmos_eksetasis>
            <imerominia_eksetasis>xxx</imerominia_eksetasis>
            <amka>14385</amka>
            <surname>??µ?t????</surname>
            <name>Ga?????</name>
            <onoma_patros>??a??????</onoma_patros>
            <imgennisis>15/03/1984</imgennisis>
            <diagnosi>G??p?</diagnosi>
            <famagogi>depon</famagogi>
        </stoixeia_astheni>
        <stoixeia_epikoinonias>
            <dieuthinsi>xxxxx</dieuthinsi>
            <takodikas>xxxxx</takodikas>
            <perioxi>xxxx</perioxi>
            <stathero>xxxxx</stathero>
            <kinito>-</kinito>
        </stoixeia_epikoinonias>
        <loipa_stoixeia>
            <fylo>A??e?</fylo>
            <oikkatastasi>?a?t?eµ????</oikkatastasi>
            <epaggelma>??e????</epaggelma>
            <istoriko>-</istoriko>
            <sxolia>-</sxolia>
        </loipa_stoixeia>
    </patient>
</patients>
```

And i am trying to search it with the following code:

```
try {
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for(int i =0;i<nl.getLength();i++) {
        Node n = nl.item(i); 
        pw.println("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><h2>Στοιχεία ασθενή</h2></td></tr>");
        for(int j=1;j<=9;j=j+1){
            pw.println("<tr>");
            pw.println("<td>"+ellhnika[j]+"</td>");
            pw.println("<td>"+n.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode().getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(j).getTextContent()+"</td>");
            pw.println("</tr>");
        }
        pw.println("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><h2>Στοιχεία επικοινωνίας</h2></td></tr>");
        for(int j=10;j<=15;j++){
            pw.println("<tr>");
            pw.println("<td>"+ellhnika[j]+"</td>");
            pw.println("<td>"+n.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode().getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(j).getTextContent()+"</td>");
            pw.println("</tr>");  
        }
        pw.println("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><h2>Λοιπά στοιχεία</h2></td></tr>");
        for(int j=16; j<=19;j++){
            pw.println("<tr>");
            pw.println("<td>"+ellhnika[j]+"</td>");
            pw.println("<td>"+n.getNodeName()+"</td>");
            pw.println("</tr>");
        } 
    }
    pw.println("</table></body></html>");
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is when the first (out of three) loop runs i show something like:

```html
<tr>
    <td>Αριθμός εξέτασης</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ημερομηνία εξέτασης</td>
    <td>
        </td>
</tr>
```

so for oddd values of j

```
n.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode().getChildNodes()
 .item(1).getChildNodes().item(j).getTextContent()
```

returns an empty value..

Any help would be usefull

Comment: Please don't just dump vast quantities of code into Stack Overflow. Instead, invest some effort in reducing this down to the simplest possible test case.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth My friend, i don't know where the error is to show you only the simplest possible  testcase..Can you help me or not?

Comment: Then start by incrementally simplifying the input data, and incrementally simplifying the code logic. Keep going until you have maybe 15 lines of code, and then repost.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `pw.println("<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><h2>Στοιχεία ασθενή</h2></td></tr>");
                    for(int j=1;j<=9;j=j+1){
                        pw.println("<tr>");
                        pw.println("<td>"+ellhnika[j]+"</td>");
                        pw.println("<td>"+n.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode().getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes().item(j).getTextContent()+"</td>");
                        pw.println("</tr>");`

i think here is my mistake. for odd values of j it returns an empty value.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: This is not a debugging service. If nobody other than you would ever be interested in our answers, you question is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 2):

Observe your program output carefully. You'll notice two things:

- It's the *even* rows (not odd that) you seem to be having problems with
- Your child nodes *are not* getting *skipped* (2nd node shows up at 3rd place)

The `org.w3c.dom.Document` has never lend itself to Java programmatic access easily. Perhaps, that's why we have APIs like JDOM that simplifies XML data access. One of the idiosyncrasies is that the text content is a separate `Node` in itself and that it includes ***whitespaces*** as well.

So, while you seem to be under the impression that you have only nine child nodes (apparent by your `for` loop condition) you actually have 18 there including the text nodes that represent the whitespace between the other nodes you're actually interested in printing the values of.

So, print your text nodes as follows

```
// fetch your child nodes just ONCE; outside the loop
NodeList childNodes = n.getParentNode().getParentNode().getParentNode()
                      .getChildNodes().item(1).getChildNodes();

// iterate over the complete list; DON'T hardcode the num of children here
for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
    String textContent = null;

    // trim to eliminate whitespace nodes
    if (!(textContent = childNodes.item(j).getTextContent().trim()).isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("<tr>");
        System.out.println("<td>" + ellhnika[j] + "</td>");
        System.out.println("<td>" + textContent + "</td>");
        System.out.println("</tr>");
    }
}
```

Do the same with the rest of your loops.